# Set Autodesk Forge Viewer to Infinity Pool environment

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Im trying to set the Infinity pool environment on the viewer but it doesn't change, it still has the initial grey background, any ideas? I'm trying to set the light preset in the ondocumentLoadSuccess Callback

```
var viewer;

function launchViewer(urn, accessToken, expires) {

    var options = {
        env: 'AutodeskProduction',
        api: 'derivativeV2',  // for models uploaded to EMEA change this option to 'derivativeV2_EU'
        getAccessToken: function (onTokenReady) {
            var token = accessToken;
            var timeInSeconds = expires; // Use value provided by Forge Authentication (OAuth) API
            onTokenReady(token, timeInSeconds);
        }
    };

    Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function () {

        var htmlDiv = document.getElementById('forgeViewer');
        viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Viewer3D(htmlDiv);
        var startedCode = viewer.start();
        if (startedCode > 0) {
            console.error('Failed to create a Viewer: WebGL not supported.');
            return;
        }

        console.log('Initialization complete, loading a model next...');

    });

    var documentId = 'urn:' + urn;
    Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
}

function onDocumentLoadSuccess(viewerDocument) {
    viewer.setLightPreset(7);
    var defaultModel = viewerDocument.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
    viewer.loadDocumentNode(viewerDocument, defaultModel);
}

function onDocumentLoadFailure(viewerErrorCode) {
    console.error('onDocumentLoadFailure() - errorCode:' + viewerErrorCode);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some cases the model you are loading into the viewer may be trying to set its own environment. Try calling the `viewer.setLightPreset` method *after* the model is loaded.

Comment: Thanks, i couldn't get the on model load success callback to fire with v7 viewer but i reverted to v6 and this works!